# RxKotlin - Dynamic observers array

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I'm using RxKotlin together with Retrofit 2

I'm trying figure out how to have dynamic list of observers on a single operation.

The first observer should trigger the operation, and all additional observers should wait until the operation complete/fails

Once the operation complete,I need to make data manipulation (Store in cache/Memory) and then notify all the observers.

Here's what I did:

```
class UserManager
{
    val observers = ArrayList<Observer<ArrayList<User>>>()
    var isFetchingUsers = false

    fun getUsers(observer: Observer<ArrayList<User>>)
    {
        observers.add(observer)

        if (isFetchingUsers)
        {
            return
        }

        api.getUserList.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(object : Observer<UserListResponse>
        {
            override fun onNext(response: UserListResponse)
            {
                // Do some manipulations on the response and notify all

                observers.forEach {
                    it.onNext(response.getUsers())
                }
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable)
            {
                observers.forEach {
                    it.onError(Throwable())
                }
            }

            override fun onComplete()
            {
                isFetchingUsers = false
                observers.clear()
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable)
            {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here's Retrofit observable creation (this one is in Java..)

```
   /**
     * Get users
     */
    public Observable<UserListResponse> getUserList()
    {
        return mService.getUserList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
```

I'm sure there's a better way for doing this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `share()` operator on an observable. Only the first subscription will cause the observable to do its creation process. Once the last subscriber is unsubscribed, the observable will do its destruction process.

```
Observable<Long> v;
...
Observable<Long> sharedObservable = v
  .doOnSubscribe( () -> logger.debug("subscribe") )
  .doOnUnsubscribe( () -> logger.debug("unsubscribe") )
  .share();

...
Subscription v1 = sharedObservable.subscribe();
Subscription v2 = sharedObservable.subscribe();
...
v1.unsubscribe();
v2.unsubscribe();
```

You will see that the subscribe operation only happens once. You should see that only one subscription operation happens to the original observable, and only one unsubscription.